# Difference between sending HTML string vs HTML file from express server?

Tags: html, node.js, express, http, gzip

I'm writing a Cloud Function as an express server that will need to:

- read an external `index.html`
- parse it, append/update some tags on it
- and then send it back to the user's browser as a response

Example:

**index.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Some text</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

**QUESTION**

Is this:

```
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
```

Different from this?

```
res.send('
  <html>
    <head>
      <title>Page Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <p>Some text</p>
    </body>
  </html>
');
```

Will the browser treat them differently in any way?

Can I set Cache-Control and gzip compression on both of them?

Comment: I don't think they are different in terms of performance but I'd prefer the first option - easier if you keep the resources separate from the code that serves them. Also, second option probably needs to use backticks - you can't have multiline string literals.

Comment: Thanks! But that `index.html` won't be inside my server. I'll need to fetch it from a URL, update it and send it back. If it's best to serve it as a file, I'll need to save in some `tmp` dir. Because this is actually a Cloud Function with an express server running on it (I'm using Firebase). I basically need to change some `<meta>` tags and send it back. What do you think?

Comment: If you need to fetch and modify it, you don't need to cache it. Well, you could but I'd start with just having that as separate functionality, so you'd do something like `res.sendFile(someModule.process("index.html"))` where `someModule` will handle that work. If you want to cache it, it would be simple to do without touching the serving code.

Comment: So I can just fetch it, parse it, update it and send it back? All of that in my function's local scope variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sendFile()` differs from `send()` in that it's going to automatically set the `Content-Type` header for you, based on a guess from the file name extension.

> Can I set Cache-Control and gzip compression on both of them?

Yes, whatever happens downstream is independent from what happens in your code here.

> - read an external index.html
> - parse it, append/update some tags on it

You should use the built-in templating functionality for this instead.  See also:  https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.render

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using express.js, why not use its render function to render

Comment: It's static content. I don't think I need to render it. I'm new to `express` but I think render is for templates, isn't it?

Comment: Not just templates but also you can render html files.

Comment: Thanks. But I don't get it. If it's just a string, what would I be rendering?

Comment: Also you can use templates if you need to dynamically add/update/remove html in a static index.html file. I usually uses .ejs as standard template.